# How to make enemies move across the screen

Tags: python, pygame, flappy-bird-clone

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
import random

pygame.init()

path = os.getcwd()

bg = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/index.jpg'))

char = [
    pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/R1.png'), 0, (14 / 18)),
    pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/R2.png'), 0, (14 / 18)),
    pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/R3.png'), 0, (14 / 18)),
    pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/R4.png'), 0, (14 / 18)),
    pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/R5.png'), 0, (14 / 18)),
    pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/R6.png'), 0, (14 / 18)),
    pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/R7.png'), 0, (14 / 18)),
    pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/R8.png'), 0, (14 / 18)),
    pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/R9.png'), 0, (14 / 18)),
]

charFlipped = [
    pygame.transform.flip(char[0], False, True),
    pygame.transform.flip(char[1], False, True),
    pygame.transform.flip(char[2], False, True),
    pygame.transform.flip(char[3], False, True),
    pygame.transform.flip(char[4], False, True),
    pygame.transform.flip(char[5], False, True),
    pygame.transform.flip(char[6], False, True),
    pygame.transform.flip(char[7], False, True),
    pygame.transform.flip(char[8], False, True),
]

fireball = [
    pygame.transform.flip(pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/FB001.png'), 0, 3), True, False),
    pygame.transform.flip(pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/FB002.png'), 0, 3), True, False),
    pygame.transform.flip(pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/FB003.png'), 0, 3), True, False),
    pygame.transform.flip(pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/FB004.png'), 0, 3), True, False),
    pygame.transform.flip(pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load(f'{path}/Images/FB005.png'), 0, 3), True, False)
]

winLength = 600
winWidth = 336

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((winLength, winWidth))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Adventures")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True


class Background(object):
    def __init__(self, speed):
        self.bgx1 = 0
        self.bgx2 = self.bgx1 + winLength
        self.speed = speed

    def draw(self):
        if self.bgx1 < (0 - winLength):
            self.bgx1 = winLength
        if self.bgx2 < (0 - winLength):
            self.bgx2 = self.bgx1 + winLength

        screen.blit(bg, (self.bgx1, 0))
        screen.blit(bg, (self.bgx2, 0))

    def move(self):
        self.bgx1 -= self.speed
        self.bgx2 -= self.speed


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, vel, buffer):
        self.x = x
        self.y = 128
        self.vel = vel
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.count = 0
        self.flipped = False
        self.width = 64 * (14 / 18)

    def draw(self):
        if self.count + 1 >= 63:
            self.count = 0

        self.count += 1

        if self.flipped is False:
            screen.blit(char[self.count // 7], (self.x, self.y))

        if self.flipped is True:
            screen.blit(charFlipped[self.count // 7], (self.x, self.y))

    def move(self):
        if self.flipped is False and self.y < winWidth - self.buffer - self.width:
            self.y += self.vel
        if self.flipped is True and self.y > self.buffer:
            self.y -= self.vel


class Fireball(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.count = 0

        self.y = 100

        self.vel = 2
        self.passed = False

    def draw(self):
        if self.count + 1 >= 35:
            self.count = 0
        self.count += 1

        screen.blit(fireball[self.count // 7], (self.x, self.y))

    def move(self):
        self.x -= self.vel


background = Background(0.5)
character = Player(128, 2, 32)
meteor = Fireball(200)


def gameWindow():
    background.draw()
    character.draw()
    meteor.draw()
    pygame.display.update()


while running:

    clock.tick(60)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            character.flipped = not character.flipped

    background.move()
    character.move()

    gameWindow()
```

I am trying to make a game really similar to Flappy Bird, but I am having trouble making the fireballs move along the screen entirely, I have not even come up with a way that might even be partway successful, and this is my last resort before I go digging on the internet for someone's code. The only way to do this is to pass a list of x values and then plug those into the class, and then change the xs, then after they go off of the screen, they are removed and a new set fo xs are passed in.

Answer (score 1):

The `FireBall` class already has a `move` method. You just need to use it.

Make these changes:

In the FireBall move method:

```
def move(self):
    self.x -= self.vel
    if self.x < -100:
       self.x = 700    # restart for right side
```

In the main loop:

```
background.move()
character.move()
meteor.move()   # add this line

gameWindow()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but also do you have any way to make it so that like multiple fireballs can go at once on the screen like Flappy Bird can have up to 3 pipes on screen, any way I can do that

Comment: @BambooBlackjack975 If you have a new question, please [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). The comments section is not intended to be used to ask additional questions. Don't extend this question either, you'll have to ask a completely new question.